# VBA - Is it possible to transform a cell into a cutom hyperlink?

Tags: vba, url, hyperlink

I am wondering if it could be possible to use VBA in order to be able to transform a cell which already contains a part of the url into an active hyperlink.
To be more specific here is an example of what i've managed to work with so far:
On column B, in cell B14 i have the following formula

> =HYPERLINK("https://google.ro/"&D14,"search") -> this is only for row 14

now on cell D14 i have the last part of the URL, for example "dogs". now when i press on cell D14 it open a new browser page and takes me to that specific address.

So my question is, can i do this on a single cell using VBA, on this example in D14, without using Column B anymore? Basically is there a way to integrate the formula used in column B into VBA?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an Event-Routine for your sheet. This one will open the browser immediately when clicking on it (in the example, it is limited to column 'D')

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' Check if only 1 cell is selected 
    If Target.Rows.Count > 1 Or Target.Columns.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Column = 4 And Target.Value <> "" Then
        ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink "https://www.google.de/search?source=hp&q=" & Target.Value
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly, you need the ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink method

```
Sub TestHyperlink()

    ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink "https://google.ro/" & Range("D14")

End Sub
```

You may need to qualify the Range("D14") with the worksheet name depending where you're calling your code from.